# Why are confidence intervals generated by metafor (rma.mv function) wider than in Comprehensive Meta Analysis (CMA) software?

Tags: confidence-interval, random-effects-model, meta-analysis, metafor

I have been asked to compare my meta-analytic results obtained from the CMA software to the results from metafor. I find that the width of my confidence intervals are larger with metafor than with CMA, and I would like to better understand the driving cause of this.

My code is as follows:

mod.model <- rma.mv(yi = r_Z,
V = v_Z,
slab = Study,
data = FullCSIData,
random = ~ 1 | Study/es.id,
test = "t",
method = "REML",
mods = ~ Measure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CMA cannot fit such a multilevel model. This model accounts for dependence in the underlying true r-to-z transformed correlation coefficients (I assume this is what you are analyzing based on the name of the `r_Z` variable). If that dependence is strong, then this will tend to lead to wider CIs, since the 'effective number of estimates' is actually lower than the number of correlation coefficients you have.